# How to create a point moving from A to B javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
var draw = function(a, b, t) {
  $.lineWidth = 2.8;
  $.fillStyle = 'hsla(277, 95%, 55%, 1)';
  $.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  for (var i = -5; i < 5; i += 1) {
    $.strokeStyle = 'hsla(151, 75%, 62%, 1)';
    $.beginPath();
    $.moveTo(0, h / 2);
    for (var j = 0; j < w; j += 10) {
      $.lineTo(10 * Math.sin(i / 10) +
        j + 0.058 * j * j,
        Math.floor(h / 2 + j / 2 *
          Math.sin(j / 50 - t / 50 - i / 118) +
          (i * 0.9) * Math.sin(j / 25 - (i + t) / 65)));
    };
    $.stroke();
  }
}
var t = 0;
```

- With the current code, it will appear immediately 
- I want it to appear from the left and move to the right 
Can anyone help me?

demo code is [here](https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/RWLbEy).